# How is mounting samba share in terminal different to mounting in Nautilus?

Tags: networking, mount, permissions, nautilus, samba

I have a server operating a samba share that I can happily navigate by browsing the network, finding the server and share. When I open the share I'm asked to log in. I use my username and password and have full access to the drive and its shares.

When I attempt to mount the same server and share with the same login details, the permissions on the share are all different. What is the difference between the two methods and how can I mount a share with the same permissions that nautilus can? I am using the command:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o user=<username> //<IP>/<share>/ <share_folder>/
```

The problem is a lot of software does not know how to open and save files to/from a network share in nautilus, so I need to mount it to the local file system.

Comment: Nautilus does the equivalent of `gvfs-mount`.